# Filtering for dates in a lookup call via AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, filters, lookup-filter

we need a date filtered rowset from a data extension in an user's email via AMPScript but the lookup function does not include a filter option.
The rowset we want to retrieve shall have a greater (older) date than the comparing date.

Has anybody an idea on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through all dates and use a conditional to select only those rows in the row-set that qualify.

The SFMC Lookup function selection criteria only supports exact AND matches.